# Прерывание в микроконтроллерах

Tags: gcc, arm, микроконтроллеры, embedded, avr-gcc

Я занимаюсь ПО для микроконтроллеров. Часе всего для чистого железа без ОС.
Как правило ARM или MIPS архитектуры.

У меня возник вопрос. Больше исследовательского характера.

Предположим срабатывает прерывание.
Можно ли каким либо образом. Анализируя стек, регистры мк, счетчик команд,
выяснить в какой точке программы произошло прерывание?
И сопоставить эту точку с исходным кодом ПО.

Ну например так:

1. Происходит прерывание.
2. В обработчики прерывания происходит анализ стека, регистров.
3. Обработчик отправляет данные на ПК.
4. И ПК сопоставляет данные с исходным кодом, линковачным файлом.
5. Затем ПК указывает на файл и строку исходника из которой произошло прерывание.

Возможно ли , что то подобное реализовать?

Comment: Конечно. В разных процессорах по разному, адрес следующей инструкции (куда надо вернуться) заносится либо в специальный регистр, либо на вершину стека. В некоторых процессорах место сохранения можно конфигурировать (в т.ч. в зависимости от типа прерывания)

Comment: Найти адрес возврата возможно. Но как это адрес сопоставить с реальным кодом?

Comment: Если программа транслировалась с  флагом отладчика (в gcc `-g`), то компилятор делает таблицу соответствия адресов со строками исходного кода и помещает ее в секцию elf-файла. Отладчик использует ее

Comment: Программа работает без отладчика.   Условно круглые сутки. Или я что то упускаю. Да, флаг отладки  установлен.  Может вы расширенно напишете , что имели ввиду.

Comment: Тут надо изучать [remote debugging](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/gdb/gdb/gdb_18.html). Насколько я понимаю, у gdb есть remote debugging protocol. Ваша программа на ПК, которой обработчик из контроллера отправляет данные, должна его поддерживать. Тогда gdb сможет соединиться с ней и его можно будет использовать для отладки

Comment: Удаленная отладка не возможна и не рассматривается. Удаленный ПК собирает только логи. Я хочу именно по отладочным сообщениям восстановить ситуацию которая произошла. И в каком месте.

Comment: Тогда вам надо разобраться с форматом секций, которые компилятор делает для отладчика в elf-е. Получив на ПК адрес прерывания (скорее вас интересуют exceptions, а не interrupts (но в принципе они похожи)) вы сами должны найти в этих секциях, какой строке исходника соответствует адрес. Я думал, что использовать готовый отладчик менее хлопотно

Comment: (вообще, это можно сделать и глазами. Запускаете objdump и получаете из elf dump (дизассемблер). Потом ищете там адрес прерывания и смотрите ассемблерный код (где-то перед этим местом в виде комментария будет исходный код (но он не всегда совпадает)))

Comment: Дело в том , что получив elf файл, можно увидеть ассемблер. Но адресация в этом ассемблерном коде не будет соответствовать реальность. Так как при загрузке код будет размещен со смещением.  На ПК я планирую получить не адрес прерывания,  а  адрес возврата из прерывания.

Comment: Говоря, адрес прерывания, я имею в виду адрес в коде программы *гда произошло прерывание* (возврат происходит по этому адресу), а не адрес обработчика, конечно же. У вас на контроллере какая-то ОС, которая читает elf и грузит код, перенастраивая его адреса?

Comment: нет. у меня чистое железо.

Comment: нет. у меня чистое железо. наверное адрес кода прерывания можно сопоставить с самой прошивкой которую я зашиваю в микроконтроллер.  А есть какое то обратное сопоставление бинарного файла с исходниками ? какая то утилита

Comment: Для сопоставления я использую objdump. И при отладке печать в uart (в т.ч. адресов (кода, стека и т.п.)). И внимательное чтение документации на железо  (до сих пор мне этого всегда хватало (почему у вас адреса в железе не соответствуют адресам в elf (из которого, как я думаю, вы получаете прошивку) я не представляю))